# OpenStack – Instance not respoding

Tags: openstack

I have an issue with OpenStack. I'm using OpenStack as a Service and trying to get an instance to respond to ping. Can someone help getting the connection to work?

I've tried to ping and SSH to the floating IP with no response.
I've also tried to ping the external network gateway IP with no response.
What more should I try?

**I have done this:**

- Created an private network with subnet
- Assigned public DNS name servers to the subnet
- Created a router and connected the private net with the external network
- Created a predefined Ubuntu instance and turned it on
- Assigned a security group that allows everything on all ports
- Connected the instance to a private network so it has a private IP address
- Associated a floating IP to the instance so it has 1 private and 1 public address

**See the attached images from the Horizon dashboard:**

[Network Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMVh6.png) – 
Image of the router. Could it be the disabled interface that is causing this?

[Instance info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HS4o.png) – 
The instance have IP addresses and security group

[Router info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQDTo.png) – 
The router is connected to the public network. You can see the provider gateway IP.

**Regards,**

Christoffer

Comment: Rather than editing the answer into your question please post it as an answer *(you're allowed to answer your own questions and accept those as the solution)*

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is now solved**
The problem was a "hidden" security group assigned to the router port that blocked all external traffic to the private network.