# Openstack : Instance can't be accessed

Tags: cloud, openstack

I installed Openstack Train minimal on centos7 virtualbox host. I can create and run instances but i can't access them via ssh or vnc. The instance is running on provider network. When i was reading the log files i found this.
[Instance Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BDkB.png)

It seems that the instance is leasing IP from Provider Network DHCP server with no errors but can't ping to gateway(192.168.1.1).
PS:I used linuxbridge to set up networking and added the ssh and icmp rules on security group.

I also saw this post
[OpenStack – Instance not respoding](https://serverfault.com/questions/961637/openstack-instance-not-respoding) but it was done on self service network.

PS: I launched my instance with **--config-drive=true** option.
PS2 : The connectivity to controller and compute node is fine.

**Edit 1:**

I enabled the ipv4 forwarding on compute node which was turned off but it did not solve the problem. So I deleted the provider network, instance and created the network and instance again. This time no --config-drive options and here is the instance bootup log.

Here is the full log:
https://pastebin.com/ywEMgAbq

My guess is instance can't connect with memcached server. (I'm currently working on it)

Comment: Does this router exist in the first place? Does Virtualbox provide connectivity from the instance to this router? Can the instance access other addresses on its network?

Comment: I used physical router and virtualbox machines connect to it using bridged adapter

Comment: You say "no router", and "I used physical router". This confuses me; is there a router with 192.168.1.1 or is there not? It's weird that the instance gets a reply from the external DHCP server but has no other connectivity to the external network. My first step would be tracing traffic on the VirtualBox bridge and on the Cloud server's external NIC to find out whether the problem is caused by anything outside of the cloud, e.g. VirtualBox, or by the cloud configuration itself.

Comment: Yea i'm sorry that i confused you.(i thought that i need additional virtual router.) Yeah there is physical router with gateway address of 192.168.1.1. And the connectivity between the router and vm is fine.

Comment: You confuse me again. You say "can't ping to gateway(192.168.1.1)", then "connectivity between the router and vm is fine". If connectivity is fine, which question are you asking?

Comment: I mean the created instance inside compute node cant ping to gateway. The compute node (the vm) is connected. When i say vm its either control or compute node. And the issue is on the created instance on node.